# MS Word Can't delete comments

Tags: ms-word

I have a Word Document (.docX) with comments on it and I need to delete them but don't seem to be able to do so..

If I right-click a comment the `Delete Comment` option is disabled and when I go to the `Review` tab, the Delete-option (in the `Comments` section) is disabled as well. And if I click `Delete All Comments in Document` nothing happens.

Afterwards I tried the same thing but with `Track Changes` disabled and all Changes accepted but the issue continues.

I have done some research and a lot of results said that maybe I can't delete them because someone else wrote them. But that can't be the case because I was already able to delete  comments before. Does anyone know why I can't delete them and what I should do to be able to do so?

EDIT:

I just checked a previous version of the document and the comments I can't delete now are "impossible" to delete there as well. So there's nothing that I did that caused for me to be unable to remove those comments.

Comment: This often occurs because you are in the middle of adding a comment. Click in any "add comment" or "reply" input box to jump to the comment you are making. Either add that comment or choose not to; then, you should be able to delete a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you save the file as a .doc file you can remove the comments. Afterwards, just restore it back to .docX if necessary.

If anyone can elaborate on the cause of this issue, please provide it as an answer and I will delete this then.

Comment: Kind of a ridiculous solution but it did work for me. Thanks

Comment: See my solution to this question. Is probably some lock which initiates if you are already editing a comment. When you post your comment you can delete other comments at your hearts content.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue and one of my coworkers has figured out how to fix it.  It is due to the content being protected in the .docx file.  If you highlight the item (either text or cell) that the comment was made on, right click, there should be an option to stop protecting the content (I forget the exact phrasing).  When you remove that protection, the comment can then be deleted normally.

Answer (score 1):

If you start writing a comment and try to delete a different comment this could happen. It looks like Word does not allow deleting comments while you are already editing one. Just post your first comment and the delete option will be available again.

Answer (score 0):

Save as "doc" does not work. Right-click on selected text shows nothing like "unprotect". Cannot delete single comments or all. Even though I can choose "delete all comments" if I create a new comment, only the new comment is deleted. Cannot turn off comment view either. (I can unselect the option, so it has no checkmark in "Show Markup" menu, but comments continue to show). As far as I can tell, comments are a permanent part of the file and cannot be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I saved mine as .doc and there is a drop-down menu in the left top corner of the comment. If you click it it gives a delete option.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in a document that had controls in it.  In the developer tab, enable "Design Mode".  Then delete all comments will work.  Afterwards disable design more to have drop downs and fields work correctly again.